# How to block NULL values on unique key?

Tags: mysql

I have the following problem. My table structure is like this:

```
//table1
id
name

//table2
id
name

//mastertable
id
table1_id
table2_id
```

And `mastertable` has foreign keys for `table1` and `table2` **but** can only use either of them for each row, and the other will be `NULL`.

The problem is, I can't have a duplicate in the rows, like:

```
{ table1_id: 1, table2_id: NULL}
{ table1_id: 1, table2_id: NULL}
```

But MySQL does allow that, since I'm using a `NULL` value on `table2_id`. And I **need** those two columns to be nullable, otherwise I can't have foreign keys on them (for example, if I used 0 instead of `NULL`).

Any way to get around this?

**Edit:** in case it wasn't clear, the table already has a unique key for `table1_id` and `table2_id`.

**Another edit:** I'm thinking of breaking the unique key into two, one for each table. Would that work, or would it come back to bite me later?

Comment: If table1 and table2 are the same structure, then add a column to table1 to hold `what the difference is` and use only one table drop table2

Comment: They aren't actually the same, that's just an example of my issue

Comment: How can you insert "table1_id: 1" multiple times if you have an unique constraint on (table1_id)? There's something you are not telling us.

Comment: @TheImpaler not really, I am using a compound index on `table1_id` and `table2_id`, which fails to check for uniqueness if one of the values is `NULL` (which is standard MySQL behavior, and is also stated on my question)

Comment: If I understand your requirement correctly, you need to define two more `UNIQUE` indices, individually on `table1_id` and `table2_id` (separately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want using MySQL 5.7's virtual/generated columns. This requires the storage of an extra column in your table, but will prevent your duplicate cases:

```
create table t1 (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(30)
);

create table t2 (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(30)
);

create table master (
  id int primary key not null,
  table1_id int,
  table2_id int,
  composite_value varchar(30) as 
    (concat(coalesce(table1_id, -1), ':', coalesce(table2_id, -1))),
  constraint fk01 foreign key (table1_id) references t1 (id),
  constraint fk02 foreign key (table2_id) references t2 (id),
  constraint uq1 unique (composite_value)
);

insert into t1 (id, name) values (1, 'Chicago');
insert into t1 (id, name) values (2, 'Detroit');
insert into t2 (id, name) values (50, 'Anne');
insert into t2 (id, name) values (51, 'James');

insert into master (id, table1_id, table2_id) values (10, 1, 50);
insert into master (id, table1_id, table2_id) values (11, 1, 51);

insert into master (id, table1_id, table2_id) values (12, 1, 50); -- fails
insert into master (id, table1_id, table2_id) values (20, 1, null); -- succeeds
insert into master (id, table1_id, table2_id) values (21, 1, null); -- fails
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: What's wrong with your first answer? It looks correct.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel It does not allow (1, 50) and then (1, 51) because of the UNIQUE constraint on `table1_id`.

Comment: (1, 50) and (1, 51) seems not to be permitted by design: "but can only use either of them for each row, and the other will be NULL".

Comment: However - I would use `concat_ws(':', table1_id, table2_id)` for the generated column.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried multiple column index?

If not, an alternative solution (mostly reliable) would be is to have a script to check the row if it exist or not. Not wrong to use that as well.

Comment: Yeah, the multi-column index is exactly the problem. I could do the checks with scripts but a foreign key would definitely be better if I can have it

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra columon to masterable which will be a unique ID, generated using `table1_id` and `table2_id`.

`masterable
|   id   | table1_id | table2_id |
| 1-null | 1         | null      |
| null-2 | null      | 2         |
| 1-null | 1         | null      |` <<< ERROR Duplicated ID